# SQL Oracle integrity constraint violated - parent key not found script generated from Vertabelo

Tags: sql, oracle, datagrip

Please help me, I'm doing a school database project and I keep getting SQL Oracle integrity constraint violated - parent key not found while trying to insert data into tables. I generated ddl script from Vertabelo and dml I created on my own. I tried everything I don't know what to do, I use datagrip on mac If it helps in anyway.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

-- tables
-- Table: Dostawca_Produkt
CREATE TABLE Dostawca_Produkt (
    Firma integer  NOT NULL,
    Produkt integer  NOT NULL,
    ilosc integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Dostawca_Produkt_pk PRIMARY KEY (Produkt,Firma)
) ;

-- Table: Firma
CREATE TABLE Firma (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    nazwa varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    miasto varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    ulica varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Firma_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Kategoria
CREATE TABLE Kategoria (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    nazwa varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Kategoria_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Kategoria_Produkt
CREATE TABLE Kategoria_Produkt (
    Produkt integer  NOT NULL,
    Kategoria integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Kategoria_Produkt_pk PRIMARY KEY (Produkt,Kategoria)
) ;

-- Table: Klient
CREATE TABLE Klient (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    Osoba integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Klient_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Klient_Newsletter
CREATE TABLE Klient_Newsletter (
    Klient integer  NOT NULL,
    Newsletter integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Klient_Newsletter_pk PRIMARY KEY (Klient,Newsletter)
) ;

-- Table: Kurier
CREATE TABLE Kurier (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    Osoba integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Kurier_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Miasto
CREATE TABLE Miasto (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    nazwa varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Miasto_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Newsletter
CREATE TABLE Newsletter (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    nazwa varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    opis varchar2(250)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Newsletter_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Osoba
CREATE TABLE Osoba (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    imie varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    nazwisko varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    email varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    numer_telefonu number(9,0)  NOT NULL,
    adres varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    Miasto integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Osoba_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Produkt
CREATE TABLE Produkt (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    nazwa varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    ilosc integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Produkt_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Produkt_Zamowienie
CREATE TABLE Produkt_Zamowienie (
    Produkt integer  NOT NULL,
    Zamowienie integer  NOT NULL,
    ilosc integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Produkt_Zamowienie_pk PRIMARY KEY (Produkt,Zamowienie)
) ;

-- Table: Status
CREATE TABLE Status (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    status_wysylki varchar2(40)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Status_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- Table: Zamowienie
CREATE TABLE Zamowienie (
    ID integer  NOT NULL,
    Klient integer  NOT NULL,
    Kurier integer  NOT NULL,
    Status integer  NOT NULL,
    data_zlozenia_zamowienia date  NOT NULL,
    data_wysylki date  NOT NULL,
    data_dostarczenia date  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Zamowienie_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;

-- foreign keys
-- Reference: Firma_Dostawca_Produkt (table: Dostawca_Produkt)
ALTER TABLE Dostawca_Produkt ADD CONSTRAINT Firma_Dostawca_Produkt
    FOREIGN KEY (Firma)
    REFERENCES Firma (ID);

-- Reference: Kategoria_Kategoria_Produkt (table: Kategoria_Produkt)
ALTER TABLE Kategoria_Produkt ADD CONSTRAINT Kategoria_Kategoria_Produkt
    FOREIGN KEY (Kategoria)
    REFERENCES Kategoria (ID);

-- Reference: Klient_Klient_Newsletter (table: Klient_Newsletter)
ALTER TABLE Klient_Newsletter ADD CONSTRAINT Klient_Klient_Newsletter
    FOREIGN KEY (Klient)
    REFERENCES Klient (ID);

-- Reference: Klient_Zamowienie (table: Zamowienie)
ALTER TABLE Zamowienie ADD CONSTRAINT Klient_Zamowienie
    FOREIGN KEY (Klient)
    REFERENCES Klient (ID);

-- Reference: Kurier_Zamowienie (table: Zamowienie)
ALTER TABLE Zamowienie ADD CONSTRAINT Kurier_Zamowienie
    FOREIGN KEY (Kurier)
    REFERENCES Kurier (ID);

-- Reference: Miasto_Osoba (table: Osoba)
ALTER TABLE Osoba ADD CONSTRAINT Miasto_Osoba
    FOREIGN KEY (Miasto)
    REFERENCES Miasto (ID);

-- Reference: Newsletter_Klient_Newsletter (table: Klient_Newsletter)
ALTER TABLE Klient_Newsletter ADD CONSTRAINT Newsletter_Klient_Newsletter
    FOREIGN KEY (Newsletter)
    REFERENCES Newsletter (ID);

-- Reference: Osoba_Klient (table: Klient)
ALTER TABLE Klient ADD CONSTRAINT Osoba_Klient
    FOREIGN KEY (Osoba)
    REFERENCES Osoba (ID);

-- Reference: Osoba_Kurier (table: Kurier)
ALTER TABLE Kurier ADD CONSTRAINT Osoba_Kurier
    FOREIGN KEY (Osoba)
    REFERENCES Osoba (ID);

-- Reference: Produkt_Dostawca_Produkt (table: Dostawca_Produkt)
ALTER TABLE Dostawca_Produkt ADD CONSTRAINT Produkt_Dostawca_Produkt
    FOREIGN KEY (Produkt)
    REFERENCES Produkt (ID);

-- Reference: Produkt_Kategoria_Produkt (table: Kategoria_Produkt)
ALTER TABLE Kategoria_Produkt ADD CONSTRAINT Produkt_Kategoria_Produkt
    FOREIGN KEY (Produkt)
    REFERENCES Produkt (ID);

-- Reference: Produkt_Produkt_Zamowienie (table: Produkt_Zamowienie)
ALTER TABLE Produkt_Zamowienie ADD CONSTRAINT Produkt_Produkt_Zamowienie
    FOREIGN KEY (Produkt)
    REFERENCES Produkt (ID);

-- Reference: Status_Zamowienie (table: Zamowienie)
ALTER TABLE Zamowienie ADD CONSTRAINT Status_Zamowienie
    FOREIGN KEY (Status)
    REFERENCES Status (ID);

-- Reference: Zamowienie_Produkt_Zamowienie (table: Produkt_Zamowienie)
ALTER TABLE Produkt_Zamowienie ADD CONSTRAINT Zamowienie_Produkt_Zamowienie
    FOREIGN KEY (Zamowienie)
    REFERENCES Zamowienie (ID);


-- Dostawca_Produkt values
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 2, 10);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 3, 15);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (2, 4, 20);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (3, 5, 20);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (4, 6, 20);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (5, 7, 25);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (6, 8, 5);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (7, 9, 10);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (8, 10, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (8, 11, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (8, 12, 45);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (9, 13, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (9, 14, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (9, 15, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (10, 16, 45);

-- Firma values
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (1, 'ABC Corporation', 'Nowy Jork', 'ul. Broadway 123');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (2, 'XYZ Industries', 'Los Angeles', 'ul. Hollywood 456');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (3, 'PQR Limited', 'Londyn', 'ul. Oxford 789');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (4, '123 Enterprises', 'Toronto', 'ul. Queen 321');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (5, 'GHI Solutions', 'Sydney', 'ul. Harbour 987');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (6, 'ABC Elektronika', 'Paryż', 'ul. Handlowa 6');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (7, 'ElektroHurt', 'Warszawa', 'ul. Magazynowa 7');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (8, 'MegaTech', 'Hongkong', 'ul. Technologiczna 8');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (9, 'ElectroMaster', 'Berlin', 'ul. Elektryczna 9');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (10, 'Elektronix', 'Warszawa', 'ul. Elektronowa 10');

-- Kategoria values
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (1, 'Telewizory');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (2, 'Smartfony');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (3, 'Laptopy');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (4, 'Konsole');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (5, 'Aparaty');

-- Kategoria_Produkt values
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (6, 2);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (7, 3);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (8, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (9, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (10, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (11, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (12, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (13, 5);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (14, 5);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (15, 5);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (16, 5);

-- Klient values
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (5, 5);

-- Klient_Newsletter values
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (5, 3);

-- Kurier values
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (1, 6);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (4, 9);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (5, 10);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (6, 11);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (7, 12);

-- Miasto values
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (1, 'Warszawa');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (2, 'Kraków');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (3, 'Gdańsk');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (4, 'Poznań');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (5, 'Wrocław');

-- Newsletter values
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (1, 'Promocje Tygodnia', 'Otrzymuj najnowsze promocje na produkty w naszym sklepie.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (2, 'Nowości w Asortymencie', 'Bądź na bieżąco z najnowszymi produktami dostępnymi w naszym sklepie.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (3, 'Informacje o Dostawach', 'Dowiedz się o najświeższych informacjach dotyczących dostaw i terminów realizacji zamówień.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (4, 'Aktualności ze Świata Technologii', 'Bądź na bieżąco z nowinkami technologicznymi i najnowszymi produktami elektronicznymi.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (5, 'Porady i Inspiracje', 'Otrzymuj przydatne porady i inspiracje związane z naszymi produktami.');

-- Osoba values
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (1, 'Jan', 'Kowalski', 'jan.kowalski@example.com', 123456789, 'ul. Słoneczna 1', 1);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (2, 'Anna', 'Nowak', 'anna.nowak@example.com', 987654321, 'ul. Kwiatowa 2', 2);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (3, 'Piotr', 'Wójcik', 'piotr.wojcik@example.com', 555555555, 'ul. Polna 3', 3);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (4, 'Marta', 'Kowalczyk', 'marta.kowalczyk@example.com', 111111111, 'ul. Leśna 4', 4);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (5, 'Michał', 'Lewandowski', 'michal.lewandowski@example.com', 999999999, 'ul. Wesoła 5', 5);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (6, 'Marek', 'Nowak', 'marek.nowak@example.com', 555111222, 'ul. Kwiatowa 6', 1);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (7, 'Agnieszka', 'Kowalska', 'agnieszka.kowalska@example.com', 999888777, 'ul. Słoneczna 7', 2);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (8, 'Grzegorz', 'Wiśniewski', 'grzegorz.wisniewski@example.com', 444333222, 'ul. Polna 8', 3);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (9, 'Katarzyna', 'Kowalczyk', 'katarzyna.kowalczyk@example.com', 111222333, 'ul. Leśna 9', 4);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (10, 'Piotr', 'Lewandowski', 'piotr.lewandowski@example.com', 777666555, 'ul. Wesoła 10', 5);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (11, 'Tomasz', 'Kowalczyk', 'tomasz.kowalczyk@example.com', 111222333, 'ul. Kwiatowa 6', 1);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (12, 'Magdalena', 'Wójcik', 'magdalena.wojcik@example.com', 444555666, 'ul. Polna 7', 2);

-- Produkt values
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (1, 'Telewizor LED 50"', 10);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (2, 'Telewizor OLED 55"', 15);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (3, 'Telewizor QLED 65"', 20);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (4, 'Smartfon Samsung Galaxy S21', 20);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (5, 'Smartfon iPhone 13', 18);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (6, 'Smartfon Xiaomi Mi 12', 22);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (7, 'Laptop Dell XPS 15', 30);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (8, 'Konsola PlayStation 5', 36);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (9, 'Konsola Nintendo Switch', 38);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (10, 'Konsola Xbox Series X', 40);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (11, 'Konsola PlayStation 5', 36);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (12, 'Konsola Nintendo Switch', 40);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (13, 'Aparat Canon EOS R5', 50);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (14, 'Aparat Sony Alpha A7 III', 42);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (15, 'Aparat Nikon Z7 II', 20);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (16, 'Aparat Fujifilm X100V', 20);

-- Produkt_Zamowienie values
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (16, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (10, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (7, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (4, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (5, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (1, 6, 2);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (2, 7, 1);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (3, 8, 3);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (2, 9, 4);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (12, 10, 5);

-- Status values
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (1, 'Zamówienie przyjęte');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (2, 'Wysyłka w trakcie');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (3, 'Dostarczone');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (4, 'Anulowane');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (5, 'Zwrot');

-- Zamowienie values
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, '2023-05-01', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-01');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 2, '2023-05-02', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-02');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 3, '2023-05-03', '2023-05-03', '2023-05-03');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 4, '2023-05-04', '2023-05-04', '2023-05-04');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 5, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-05', '2023-05-05');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (6, 1, 1, 1, '2023-05-06', '2023-05-06', '2023-05-06');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (7, 2, 2, 2, '2023-05-07', '2023-05-07', '2023-05-07');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (8, 3, 3, 3, '2023-05-08', '2023-05-08', '2023-05-08');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (9, 4, 4, 4, '2023-05-09', '2023-05-09', '2023-05-09');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (10, 5, 5, 5, '2023-05-10', '2023-05-10', '2023-05-10');

commit;

-- End of file.
```

Comment: What line in your script is the error being reported on?

Comment: BTW, you can simplify your SQL DDL somewhat by creating the tables in dependency order with inline `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Comment: See here: `INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 1, 5);` - you're inserting `1` for `Firma` - which means you need to `INSERT INTO Firma ( ... )` **before** inserting into `Dostawca_Produkt `.

Answer (score 0):

You are `INSERT`ing the data in the wrong order and trying to `INSERT` into tables before the table they are referencing has had any data inserted into it.

For example, this order works:

```sql
-- Firma values
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (1, 'ABC Corporation', 'Nowy Jork', 'ul. Broadway 123');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (2, 'XYZ Industries', 'Los Angeles', 'ul. Hollywood 456');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (3, 'PQR Limited', 'Londyn', 'ul. Oxford 789');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (4, '123 Enterprises', 'Toronto', 'ul. Queen 321');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (5, 'GHI Solutions', 'Sydney', 'ul. Harbour 987');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (6, 'ABC Elektronika', 'Paryż', 'ul. Handlowa 6');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (7, 'ElektroHurt', 'Warszawa', 'ul. Magazynowa 7');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (8, 'MegaTech', 'Hongkong', 'ul. Technologiczna 8');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (9, 'ElectroMaster', 'Berlin', 'ul. Elektryczna 9');
INSERT INTO Firma (ID, nazwa, miasto, ulica) VALUES (10, 'Elektronix', 'Warszawa', 'ul. Elektronowa 10');

-- Kategoria values
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (1, 'Telewizory');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (2, 'Smartfony');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (3, 'Laptopy');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (4, 'Konsole');
INSERT INTO Kategoria (ID, nazwa) VALUES (5, 'Aparaty');

-- Miasto values
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (1, 'Warszawa');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (2, 'Kraków');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (3, 'Gdańsk');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (4, 'Poznań');
INSERT INTO Miasto (ID, nazwa) VALUES (5, 'Wrocław');

-- Newsletter values
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (1, 'Promocje Tygodnia', 'Otrzymuj najnowsze promocje na produkty w naszym sklepie.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (2, 'Nowości w Asortymencie', 'Bądź na bieżąco z najnowszymi produktami dostępnymi w naszym sklepie.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (3, 'Informacje o Dostawach', 'Dowiedz się o najświeższych informacjach dotyczących dostaw i terminów realizacji zamówień.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (4, 'Aktualności ze Świata Technologii', 'Bądź na bieżąco z nowinkami technologicznymi i najnowszymi produktami elektronicznymi.');
INSERT INTO Newsletter (ID, nazwa, opis) VALUES (5, 'Porady i Inspiracje', 'Otrzymuj przydatne porady i inspiracje związane z naszymi produktami.');

-- Osoba values
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (1, 'Jan', 'Kowalski', 'jan.kowalski@example.com', 123456789, 'ul. Słoneczna 1', 1);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (2, 'Anna', 'Nowak', 'anna.nowak@example.com', 987654321, 'ul. Kwiatowa 2', 2);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (3, 'Piotr', 'Wójcik', 'piotr.wojcik@example.com', 555555555, 'ul. Polna 3', 3);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (4, 'Marta', 'Kowalczyk', 'marta.kowalczyk@example.com', 111111111, 'ul. Leśna 4', 4);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (5, 'Michał', 'Lewandowski', 'michal.lewandowski@example.com', 999999999, 'ul. Wesoła 5', 5);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (6, 'Marek', 'Nowak', 'marek.nowak@example.com', 555111222, 'ul. Kwiatowa 6', 1);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (7, 'Agnieszka', 'Kowalska', 'agnieszka.kowalska@example.com', 999888777, 'ul. Słoneczna 7', 2);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (8, 'Grzegorz', 'Wiśniewski', 'grzegorz.wisniewski@example.com', 444333222, 'ul. Polna 8', 3);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (9, 'Katarzyna', 'Kowalczyk', 'katarzyna.kowalczyk@example.com', 111222333, 'ul. Leśna 9', 4);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (10, 'Piotr', 'Lewandowski', 'piotr.lewandowski@example.com', 777666555, 'ul. Wesoła 10', 5);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (11, 'Tomasz', 'Kowalczyk', 'tomasz.kowalczyk@example.com', 111222333, 'ul. Kwiatowa 6', 1);
INSERT INTO Osoba (ID, imie, nazwisko, email, numer_telefonu, adres, Miasto) VALUES (12, 'Magdalena', 'Wójcik', 'magdalena.wojcik@example.com', 444555666, 'ul. Polna 7', 2);

-- Produkt values
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (1, 'Telewizor LED 50"', 10);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (2, 'Telewizor OLED 55"', 15);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (3, 'Telewizor QLED 65"', 20);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (4, 'Smartfon Samsung Galaxy S21', 20);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (5, 'Smartfon iPhone 13', 18);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (6, 'Smartfon Xiaomi Mi 12', 22);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (7, 'Laptop Dell XPS 15', 30);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (8, 'Konsola PlayStation 5', 36);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (9, 'Konsola Nintendo Switch', 38);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (10, 'Konsola Xbox Series X', 40);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (11, 'Konsola PlayStation 5', 36);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (12, 'Konsola Nintendo Switch', 40);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (13, 'Aparat Canon EOS R5', 50);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (14, 'Aparat Sony Alpha A7 III', 42);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (15, 'Aparat Nikon Z7 II', 20);
INSERT INTO Produkt (ID, nazwa, ilosc) VALUES (16, 'Aparat Fujifilm X100V', 20);

-- Status values
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (1, 'Zamówienie przyjęte');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (2, 'Wysyłka w trakcie');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (3, 'Dostarczone');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (4, 'Anulowane');
INSERT INTO Status (ID, status_wysylki) VALUES (5, 'Zwrot');

-- Kategoria_Produkt values
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (6, 2);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (7, 3);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (8, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (9, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (10, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (11, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (12, 4);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (13, 5);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (14, 5);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (15, 5);
INSERT INTO Kategoria_Produkt (Produkt, Kategoria) VALUES (16, 5);

-- Klient values
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO Klient (ID, Osoba) VALUES (5, 5);

-- Klient_Newsletter values
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO Klient_Newsletter (Klient, Newsletter) VALUES (5, 3);

-- Kurier values
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (1, 6);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (4, 9);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (5, 10);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (6, 11);
INSERT INTO Kurier (ID, Osoba) VALUES (7, 12);

-- Dostawca_Produkt values
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 2, 10);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (1, 3, 15);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (2, 4, 20);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (3, 5, 20);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (4, 6, 20);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (5, 7, 25);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (6, 8, 5);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (7, 9, 10);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (8, 10, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (8, 11, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (8, 12, 45);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (9, 13, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (9, 14, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (9, 15, 30);
INSERT INTO Dostawca_Produkt (Firma, Produkt, ilosc) VALUES (10, 16, 45);

-- Zamowienie values
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, '2023-05-01', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-01');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 2, '2023-05-02', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-02');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 3, '2023-05-03', '2023-05-03', '2023-05-03');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 4, '2023-05-04', '2023-05-04', '2023-05-04');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 5, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-05', '2023-05-05');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (6, 1, 1, 1, '2023-05-06', '2023-05-06', '2023-05-06');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (7, 2, 2, 2, '2023-05-07', '2023-05-07', '2023-05-07');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (8, 3, 3, 3, '2023-05-08', '2023-05-08', '2023-05-08');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (9, 4, 4, 4, '2023-05-09', '2023-05-09', '2023-05-09');
INSERT INTO Zamowienie (ID, Klient, Kurier, Status, data_zlozenia_zamowienia, data_wysylki, data_dostarczenia) VALUES (10, 5, 5, 5, '2023-05-10', '2023-05-10', '2023-05-10');

-- Produkt_Zamowienie values
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (16, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (10, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (7, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (4, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (5, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (1, 6, 2);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (2, 7, 1);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (3, 8, 3);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (2, 9, 4);
INSERT INTO Produkt_Zamowienie (Produkt, Zamowienie, ilosc) VALUES (12, 10, 5);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XEPsgLf1)